# Array Length To Limit Number of Columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to limit the number of columns pulled from a data source. The source has 10 columns, I only need the first 4 columns. Seems I am confusing myself on `userData` and `var j` plus `var k` and `var l` when attempting to create an HTML table of the output.

When I use `var i = 0; i < values.length; i++` and `var j = 0; j < header.length; j++` with `var k = 0; k < userData.length; k++` and `var l = 0; l < userData[0].length; l++` the HTML output returns all the columns.

How can I limit the output to just the first 4 columns?

```
var sheetID = 'example';
var dataSheet = 'SOP Update ACK';
var emailHeader = 'Email Address';
var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle('My SOP Updates');
}

function currentUser() {
  if (activeUser !== '') {
    return activeUser.getEmail();
  } else {
    return "Couldn't detect user!!!";
  }
}

function getData() {
  var sheetName = dataSheet;
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var header = values[0];
  var emailIndex = header.indexOf(emailHeader);
  var userData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][emailIndex] == activeUser) {
      userData.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  if (userData.length > 0) {
    var tableStart = '\n<table class="table table-hover table-sm">';
    var tableHead = '\n<thead>\n<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
      tableHead = tableHead + '\n<th>' + header[j] + '</th>';
    }
    tableHead = tableHead + '\n</tr>\n</thead>';
    var tableBody = '\n<tbody>';
    for (var k = 0; k < userData.length; k++) {
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n<tr>';
      for (var l = 0; l < userData[0].length; l++) {
        tableBody = tableBody + '\n<td>' + userData[k][l] + '</td>';
      }
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n</tr>\n';
    }
    var tableEnd = '</tbody>\n</table>';
    var tableHtml = tableStart + tableHead + tableBody + tableEnd;
    return tableHtml;
  } else {
    return '<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td>No data found.</td></tr></tbody></table>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `userData.push(values[i].slice(0,4));`.  Ref [Array.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work:

You will have to make some minor modification to get it to work for you because I tested it on my temp data since you did not provide any

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [header, ...values] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const emailIndex = header.indexOf('Email Address');
  const userData = [];
  const activeUser = Session.getActiveUser();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][emailIndex] == activeUser) {
      userData.push(values[i].slice(0,4));
    }
  }
  if (userData.length > 0) {
    let tableStart = '\n<table class="table table-hover table-sm">';
    let tableHead = '\n<thead>\n<tr>';
    for (let j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
      tableHead = tableHead + '\n<th>' + header[j] + '</th>';
    }
    tableHead += '\n</tr>\n</thead>';
    let tableBody = '\n<tbody>';
    for (let k = 0; k < userData.length; k++) {
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n<tr>';
      for (let l = 0; l < userData[0].length; l++) {
        tableBody = tableBody + '\n<td>' + userData[k][l] + '</td>';
      }
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n</tr>\n';
    }
    let tableEnd = '</tbody>\n</table>';
    let tableHtml = tableStart + tableHead + tableBody + tableEnd;
    return tableHtml;
  } else {
    return '<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td>No data found.</td></tr></tbody></table>';
  }
}
```

Comment: With this im getting no return on data at all

Comment: Did you resolve the two undefined variables?

Comment: Sure did, I updated my post with the full script I'm running. The HTML page shows, but is blank.